# Can I arrive in China with a short-term family visit visa (Q2) in a city that is not the home of my relative?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, china

I'm a UK citizen planning on visiting relatives who are Chinese citizens in China. China has a Q2 visa for this:

> | Visa Categories | Description of Visa |
> | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... |
> | Q2 | Issued to those who intend to visit their relatives who are Chinese citizens residing in China or foreigners with permanent residence in China, with an intended duration of stay in China of no more than 180 days. |
> | ... | ... |

[Reference](http://gb.china-embassy.gov.cn/eng/visa/qzxz/201303/t20130315_3383967.htm)

I was considering arriving in China via a city that was not the home of my relatives and will take the train to their city on the same day but was wondering how large the risk of being refused entry is, especially if the city of arrival is far from the home of my relative. Looking for recollections of actual experiences if you've done something similar or a reference to policy if anything is publicly accessible.

Comment: What are your specific plans? I don't know Chinese policies specifically, but in most countries, if you have a same-day connecting flight or train to your relatives' home, this would not be a problem at all; if you have no plans at all to do the thing you said your visa is for, this would be a potential problem; and if you have something in between (e.g., a trip to visit your relatives only after a week or two in your arrival city), this would be of intermediate concern.

Comment: @mlc: thanks for the question. I will take the train to their city on the same day. Have edited this detail into the question. Agreed on your comment, am thinking it wouldn't be a problem in most countries, but am wondering if other factors may significantly affect this such as the distance between the cities or the plan being viewed as unusual.

Comment: They might want to know the reason for arriving in that city.

Comment: I have no idea if it has changed after Covid, but before the pandemic, no one cared. I had never gone to where I wrote on the arrival card or visa application immediately after landing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you land has absolutely no importance. After all, your final destination may or may not have an airport, and even if it has, no direct flight to/from your own.

When applying for a Chinese visa, even a multiple-entry, we need to supply an itinerary, but this is never taken into account when actually crossing the border.

The Immigration officer who processes you in might ask you where you are going, how long you are staying, etc, but that's about it.